# In MongoDB, how to fetch recent 30 results from each id and group them by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
TestResults Model

    [
    {
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "121",
testName: "test1",
result: "pass"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "122",
testName: "test2",
result: "pass"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "123",
testName: "test3",
result: "pass"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "121",
testName: "test1",
result: "fail"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "121",
testName: "test1",
result: "fail"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "122",
testName: "test2",
result: "pass"
},
{
_id: "mongoDBObjectId",
testId: "123",
testName: "test3",
result: "fail"
},
]
```

I have to fetch recent 30 documents from each "testId", and group them by "testID",

```
[
{"testId": "121", "testDetails": [{"result": "pass", "testName": "test1"},..]},
{"testId": "122", "testDetails": [{"result": "pass", "testName": "test2"},..]},
{"testId": "123", "testDetails": [{"result": "pass", "testName": "test3"},..]},
]
```

I tried with `$match` and `$group` aggregate, please find the below code,

```
testResults.aggregate([
        {
          $match:
          {
            "testId": { "$exists": true };
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: { _id: -1 },
        },
        {
          $limit: 30
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$testId",
            testDetails: { $push: {result: "$result", testName: "$testName"} }
          }
        }
      ])
        .exec(function (err, testResults) {
          if (err)
            res.send(err);
    
          res.json(testResults);
        });
```

The above code is returning, recent 30 documents from all "testId", but I don't know how to fetch 30 recent documents from each available "testId" and group them. And also, I should not pass any specific "testId" or multiple "testId", I have to fetch from all available "testId" in collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$slice` to get 30 documents per `testId`,

- removed `$limit` because its not needed
- in last `$addFields` to use `$slice` in `testDetails` field to get top 30 elements that we ave already sorted before,

```
testResults.aggregate([
  { $match: { testId: { "$exists": true } } },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$testId",
      testDetails: {
        $push: {
          result: "$result",
          testName: "$testName"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      testDetails: { $slice: ["$testDetails", 30] }
    }
  }
])
.exec(function (err, testResults) {
  if (err) res.send(err);
  res.json(testResults);
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oMySwD2l6S5)